# TimeoutException: Message: Stacktrace: Backtrace:

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to webscrape from multiple pages, my code seems to work really well for just page one and when I use loop to do web scrapping for example first 5 pages then im getting below error:TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

**My code is below**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests as r


import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"


driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

_list=[]
for page_num in range(1,3):
    #print("----")
    url=f"https://valuebuds.com/pages/search-results-page?tab=products&page={page_num}"
    driver.get(url)
    
    Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#year_field")))).select_by_visible_text('1999')

    driver.find_element_by_class_name("agree").click()
    
    title=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("snize-overhidden")
    
    for j in title:
        Pro=j.find_element_by_class_name("snize-title").text
        Price=j.find_element_by_class_name("snize-price-list").text
        Desc=j.find_element_by_class_name("snize-description").text
    
        prec_item={
            "Product":Pro,
            "Price":Price,
            "Description":Desc
        }
        _list.append(prec_item)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(_list)

df.to_csv("Value Buds HTML Pricing.csv")

print("saved to file.")
```

---

please advise! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code block

```py
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#year_field")))).select_by_visible_text('1999')

driver.find_element_by_class_name("agree").click()
```

Is relevant when you landing the home page first time.
Once you have selected the year and clicked `Agree` button you will be able to see all the pages of presented results with no need to select that year again.
So, your code could be something like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests as r


import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

PATH="chromedriver.exe"


driver=webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

_list=[]
for page_num in range(1,3):
    #print("----")
    url=f"https://valuebuds.com/pages/search-results-page?tab=products&page={page_num}"
    driver.get(url)

    if page_num == 1:
    
        Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#year_field")))).select_by_visible_text('1999')

       driver.find_element_by_class_name("agree").click()
    else:        
        time.sleep(2)
    
    title=driver.find_elements_by_class_name("snize-overhidden")
    
    for j in title:
        Pro=j.find_element_by_class_name("snize-title").text
        Price=j.find_element_by_class_name("snize-price-list").text
        Desc=j.find_element_by_class_name("snize-description").text
    
        prec_item={
            "Product":Pro,
            "Price":Price,
            "Description":Desc
        }
        _list.append(prec_item)
        
df = pd.DataFrame(_list)

df.to_csv("Value Buds HTML Pricing.csv")

print("saved to file.")
```

I have added a delay for non-first iteration to make pages loaded before you will scrape their data.
I will be better if you use Expected Conditions explicit waits there.
I don't know what condition to use there, leaved that for you decision.

Comment: Great! You are welcome!